# Easy parallel evaluation of tuples in scala?

Tags: scala, concurrency, parallel-processing

If two expressions e1 and e2 only deal with immutable data structures, then evaluating the tuple (e1, e2) in parallel should be dead simple, just evaluate the two expressions on different processors and don't worry about any interactions, because there shouldn't be any.

Scala has lots of immutable data structures, so I would expect there to be a super simple (to write) way of evaluating that tuple in parallel. Something like

`par_tuple : ( Unit -> T1) -> (Unit -> T2) -> (T1, t2)`

which evaluates the two functions in parallel and returns when both have finished.

I haven't seen it yet, though. Does it exist? If not how would you write it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends how **costly** is the expression being evaluated is. On current architectures, two expressions involving few to dozens, even hundreds of instructions cannot be evaluated in parallel efficiently. So you should always make sure that the amount of work you're executing isn't shadowed by the cost of parallelization itself.

With this disclaimer in mind, in Scala 2.10 you can use `Future`s to accomplish this:

```
val f = future { e1 }
val g = future { e2 }
(Await.result(f), Await.result(g))
```

Note that this style of computations is discouraged (and the above is deliberately overly verbose!), because it involves blocking, and blocking on platform such as the JVM, where there is no concept of efficient continuations, is often costly (though the situations where it is applicable is beyond the scope of this answer, and probably of this answerer). In most cases you should install a callback on the future which is called once its value becomes available. You can do this instead:

```
val h = for {
  x <- f
  y <- g
} yield (x, y)
```

where `h` above is a new future which will contain a tuple of values once both become available.

You could rewrite your function `par_tuple` to either:

```
def par_tuple[E1, E2](e1: =>E1, e2: =>E2): Future[(E1, E2)] = {
  val f = future { e1 }
  val g = future { e2 }
  val h: Future[(E1, E2)] = for {
    x <- f
    y <- g
  } yield (x, y)
  h
}
```

This method returns a `Future` of the tuple you want - an object which will eventually hold the tuple with your expressions. You can compose this future further with other computations, or if you're sure you want to block, you can have another variant:

```
def par_tuple_blocking[E1, E2](e1: =>E1, e2: =>E2): (E1, E2) = Await.result(par_tuple(e1, e2))
```

which blocks until the tuple becomes available in the future.

See [more about futures, callbacks and blocking here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html).

Comment: Yes of course, for some operations parallelism isn't cost effective. I meant simple to write. If I understand you correctly, the specific function I wanted would be written: def par_tuple[T1, T2](e1 : Future[T1], e2 : Future[T2]) : (T1, T2) = for {x <- e1; y <- e2} yield (x,y)

Comment: Do you have a link for more on why blocking is bad?

Comment: Why not use only one Future and do the other work on the main thread?

Comment: Piggy-backing the caller thread would probably be more efficient, yes. As for blocking, if your application only occasionally blocks on a result of evaluating the parallel expressions, then it's probably ok. However, if your application often blocks on evaluating such expressions, then performance will deteriorate tremendously.

Comment: Blocking is /not/ inherently evil. This is a common fallacy coming from those who don't know about the effect of a lack of excess parallelism. Blocking IO operations will severely impair a single-threaded program. So the problem is that the program design is wrong, not that blocking is evil. We could go further: non-blocking programs are not event driven, so can be much harder to reason about from a concurrency perspective. So the reverse argument, non-blocking is evil, might be made. (I say this partly in jest, but the point is that these are significant design questions.)

Comment: We had a painful experience from DispatchHTTP, a non-blocking api. See http://www.bigbeeconsultants.co.uk/blog/dispatch-http-critique for further details.

Comment: Rick, I agree with the things you've said - particularly with the fact that the design of the program is wrong, and not blocking. But I also believe that a `par_tuple` method which blocks is this way may ultimately lead to a bad design. Also - the statement "blocking is evil" is a dogmatic one not holding any argument or evidence, so I don't subscribe to it personally - so I removed that citation ;).